# Selenium em Python captando apenas 1 link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Boa tarde a todos, estou começando a aprender Selenium e já me passaram um projeto para fazer que estou meio perdido.

Preciso captar todos os sumários da URL https://bgpview.io/reports/countries/BR,
que sao 8.079 ASN.

Consegui fazer apenas de 1 ANS, utilizando:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

driver=webdriver.Firefox()

site=driver.get('https://bgpview.io/reports/countries/BR')

ans=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a´).click()

extracao=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-info"]')

print (extracao.text) 

voltar=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Countries Report').click()*
```

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para pegar os 8000 restantes.

Ainda não coloquei na IDE e nem fiz as classes, pois quero primeiro entender todos os passos dentro do terminal.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Se você observar os links dos ASN que vc quer capturar tem o mesmo padrão `"https://bgpview.io/asn/+númedo da asn"`. Portanto eu partiria desse principio e capturaria todos os números dos asn e depois faria uma busca em cada link. Vou colocar um código de exemplo aqui porém só usando o [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

**Passo 1**

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
```

Aqui utilizo o request para acessar o link

**Passo 2**

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://bgpview.io/reports/countries/BR').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
```

Agora vou acessar a tabela e salvar em um dataframe

**Passo 3**

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={"id":"country-report"})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
titulo = table.find_all('th')
colunas = []
for col in titulo:
    colunas.append(col.text)
l = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    l.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=colunas)
df = df.dropna()
```

Agora vou salvar a coluna de ASN em uma lista e passar um regex para que fique somente os números que é o que a gente precisa para colocar nos links

**Passo 4**

```
asn = df['ASN'].tolist()
asn_number = []
for a in asn:
    num = re.sub("[A-Za-z]", "", a)
    asn_number.append(num)
```

Agora vamos fazer um for e passar cada número do link e salvar o resultado da extração em um dataframe:

**Passo 5**

```
from http.client import IncompleteRead
l = list()
for asn in asn_number:
    row = []
    try:
        source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://bgpview.io/asn/'+str(asn)).read()
    except IncompleteRead:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    ext=soup.find('div', attrs={"id":"content-info"})
    
    col = ext.find_all('h4')
    colunas = [tr.text.replace(":", "") for tr in col]
    
    span = ext.find_all('span')
    em = ext.find_all('em')
    
    for tr in span:
        row.append(tr.text.replace("\n", ""))
    for tr in em:
        row.append(tr.text.replace("\n", ""))
    dic = dict(zip(colunas, row))
    l.append(dic) 
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=colunas)
```

Lembrando que você pode seguir essa mesma linha de raciocínio com o selenium também, porém ele é muito mais pesado.

Comment: Legal deu certo!!!
mas como faço para salvar em csv essa lista?

Comment: No último for vc pode criar duas listas uma com o nome das colunas e outros com os valores e transformar isso em um dicionário e utilizando o pandas vc constrói o dataframe.

Comment: Vc utiliza a mesma ideia que eu mostrei no passo três só que transformando o conteúdo em dicionário e passando para a lista!